# Is there a way to right align labels with missing values in CSS without a complex setup?

Tags: html, css

I have the following right aligned and would like the labels to all line up if for example the other values are missing. In the code below I only have the Phone number and when that happens it looks awful.

```html
<div style="text-align: right">
     Phone: 555-555-5555<br/>
     Cell: <br/>
     Work: 
</div>
```

How Can I have the labels all line up nicely so that if there is a missing value it's just blank rather than what I see now?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```html
<div style="text-align: right">
  <div style="float:right;text-align:left">
     Phone: 555-555-5555<br/>
     Cell: <br/>
     Work: 
  </div>
</div>
```

Or float the parent right and the child left, but then you might need to set the widths specifically

Answer (score 2):

You can create a parent div with `float: right` and inside that, you can `text-align: left` your div:

```css
.parent{
float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div style="text-align: left">
     Phone: 555-555-5555<br/>
     Cell: <br/>
     Work: 
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this what you are after?

```css
.label {
       display: inline-block;
       width: 150px;
       text-align: right;
    }
```

```html
    <div>
         <div><span class="label">Phone:</span> <span>555-555-5555</span></div>
         <div><span class="label">Cell:</span></div>
         <div><span class="label">Work:</span></div>
    </div>
```